# Add focus/blur listener in IntelliJ plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

How can I listen for focus/blur events of all edtitors in an IntelliJ plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get `EditorEventMulticasterEx` using [`getEventMulticaster`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/193/platform/editor-ui-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/editor/EditorFactory.java#L173) method, and then use its [`addFocusChangeListener`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/193/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/openapi/editor/ex/EditorEventMulticasterEx.java#L17) method:

```
Disposable disposable = () -> {};  // or your custom disposable

EditorEventMulticasterEx editorEventMulticaster =
        (EditorEventMulticasterEx) EditorFactory.getInstance().getEventMulticaster();

editorEventMulticaster.addFocusChangeListener(new FocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void focusGained(@NotNull Editor editor) {
        // handle focus event
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(@NotNull Editor editor) {
        // handle blur event
    }
}, disposable);
```